# Optimize Javascript code to find records in array that match criteria

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a parent component which is a list of records and in one of the child component I have a form that submits data and if successful is added to that list in the parent. Everytime the data is submitted, I need to check if there is an identical record with the same title. This child form component is used to add and edit records, so if the record is edited then I also have to check that it can be submitted with the same name of ofcourse. Below is the code I have and it is working fine but I have been thinking if there is a better way of writing this. Can it be done while going thru the list array the first time instead of going through it once and then going thru it again to check for unique items.

When the data is submitted in the child component (form) I am executing the following functions to see if title field is unique.

```
const isUniqueTitle = (title) => {
  if(activities.find(activity => activity.title.toLowerCase() === title)){
    // shows alert
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// Child component/form calls this function with the form data
const validateData = data = {
let isUnique = true;
  //activities below is available here in the parent
  activities.forEach(activity => {

    // check for id below tells me that its a record being edited so only do a check if the title 
    // has been changed else if there is no id then it means its a new record so continue with the 
    // check
    if (activity.id && activity.title != activity.title) {
        isUnique = isUniqueTitle(data.title);
    } else if (!activity.id) {
        isUnique = isUniqueTitle(data.title);
    }
    return isUnique;

  })
}
```

Please advise, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store titles and use its `has` method to check for the uniqueness of any given title

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type

```
const titleSet = new Set(activities.map(activity => activity.title.toLowerCase()))

const isUniqueTitle = (title) => {
  return titleSet.has(title);
}

// Child component/form calls this function with the form data
const validateData = data = {
  //activities below is available here in the parent
  activities.forEach(activity => {

    // check for id below tells me that its a record being edited so only do a check if the title 
    // has been changed else if there is no id then it means its a new record so continue with the 
    // check
    if (activity.id && activity.title != activity.title) {
        isUniqueTitle(data.title);
    } else if (!activity.id) {
       isUniqueTitle(data.title);
    }

  })
}
```

Comment: I do like the use of Set, but we are still going over the array twice. Once with forEach and once with map inside Set. I was more looking for a solution so I go over the array just once, May be I have it right and  there is no way to achieve this without going over it twice :-) hmm thinking!

Comment: @sayayin you only have to init the `Set` whenever the `activities` changes, so basically it's just one-time initialization